# Toggle show/hide html text wrapped in Span class tags using HTML button and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a decent command of HTML and CSS but a complete newbie when it comes to Javascript.

I have a simple HTML page that I would like to include a button on, to toggle the display of text already wrapped in a span class e.g.

```
<span class="xxx">TEXT</span>
```

There are two separate span classes I'm using and ideally, I'd like the click of one button to show/hide both.

Right now I'm using CSS to hide them using the property "Display: none".

Can you show me how to achieve this? Hope this clear, thank you.

Comment: Once you have selected the elements you want to toggle, this can be done by either adjusting the classes in the `classList` property on them, or setting their inline styling with the `style` property.

Comment: [JavaScript — Dynamic client-side scripting - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (ES6):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

btn.onclick = () => { 
  for(let x of toggle) {
    x.classList.toggle('hide');
  }
};
```

```css
.toggle.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Toggle</button>
<p>Name: <span class="toggle name">John</span></p>
<p>Age: <span class="toggle age">20</span></p>
```

Comment: Hi, I added this code but nothing is happening when I click the button. Is there anything else I need to change other than the ('.text') field to match my class name? Also, I have 2 separate classes throughout the document, looks like this code is designed for one - could you add code for a second class please.

Comment: @HI2020 Run code snippet to see it working. You can use multiple classes for single element - use the same class for each span you want to toggle and leave the separate classes intact (see the edited snippet).

Comment: thanks for this, but I've tried it and it's still not working. Here's my code, please take a look and tell me where I'm going wrong: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GEUKBTZ3D7MH

Comment: @HI2020 The problem is in the way you load your document. Your file currently loads as follows (top to bottom): HTML head->JS->CSS->HTML body. Your JS just cant find the elements targeted in variables, cause they aren't yet created in the document (HTML body). If you want it to work put your JS script right after closing </body> tag. Or if you want to leave it where it is, make sure it runs after the whole document is loaded by putting it in: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // your code goes here
}, false);`

Comment: this worked! Thank you so much. As I said I'm a total newbie when it comes to JS, so I had no idea the order was important.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vanilla Javascript on ES5 syntax:

```
function toggleSpanElements() {
 var span1 = document.querySelector('#span1');
 var span2 = document.querySelector('#span2');
 span1.style.display = span1.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
 span2.style.display = span2.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Just attach that function to your button in the following way:

```
    <button onclick="toggleSpanElements()">Toggle!</button>
```

Comment: Please note I used an ID as a Selector, you could use your '.xxx' class as well, I just wanted the answer to be most clear for future searches.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I added this code but it's only showing/hiding the first instance where the classes appear and not on ALL instances in the document, how can I achieve the latter?